# Calculating LST time-servers graph

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, usgs

### i am trying to compute the time series graph of the particular location i m getting this error no idea what to do i m using "MODIS/006/MOD11A"

```
var lst = lstImg.select('LST_Day_1km')
             .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31'))
             .map(function(image){return image.clip(table)})
            .sort('CLOUD COVERAGE',false)
             .filterBounds(table);
    var lstVis = {
      min: 13000.0,
      max: 16500.0,
      palette: [
        '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
        '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
        '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
        'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
        'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
      ],
    };
    //Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
    Map.addLayer(lst,lstVis,'LST');
    print(ui.Chart.image.series(lst.select('LST_Day_1km'), table, ee.Reducer.mean(),30));
```

**ERROR**

Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.

Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.

---

### Script link

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba74a316399d35095a3d8c5a9ccabb10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very simple.  You are selecting the daily temperature reading, for 19 years.

19*365 = 6935

This is greater than the maximum allowed of 5000.

Reduce your dates to encompass less dates and it should work.

I drew a random polygon on your map, set dates from 2000-2010 and got this chart.

[image: Chart]

Comment: I have calculated  chart for ndvi and ndwi on same dates that work without problem and i cant change dates as it will cause errors in further analysis so any other  option

Comment: And  is possible to calculate same thing with landsat ?

Comment: Reduce the frequency.  For NDVI, it won't change daily, so you could probably take weekly images. this will be 52 per year, so it will reduce considerably your chart data

Comment: What it i export image and compute chart on Arcgis or qgis ?

Comment: Or can you tel me how to do that i m beginner to gis

Comment: You aren't exporting an image.  But would be exporting 6935...

Comment: how to add interval to the date
if i want to find every 3rd day LST till 19 years